# Scaling works differently in GUI and from script

Tags: mesh, scripting, 3d-cursor

I am trying to scale a group of vertices. I changed the pivot point to 3D cursor. I placed the cursor on of the corners of the square. I want to scale the vertices about this corner. When done in GUI, using the shortcut s+x (to scale along x direction) and a factor of 0.3, I get the following desired result. [image]

When I try the same from a script, by placing the 3D cursor on the same corner and then do a bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.3, 0.3, 0.3)) (or (0.3,0,0)), I get the result of what would have been if the cursor was at the centre (median) of the line as shown in the second figure.

[image]

Can someone tell why this difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a context issue and you need to [Override the Context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6105/1859)

The pivot point is a member of the 3D_VIEW space.  In code below would be `area.spaces.active.pivot_point`  Example of overriding the context which "fools" the operator into thinking it is being run from the 3D view, not the text editor.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
override = context.copy() # dictionary of context

for area in context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override["area"] = area
        override["space_data"] = area.spaces.active
        override["region"] = area.regions[-1] # rule of thumb r.type == 'WINDOW'
        break

bpy.ops.transform.resize(override,
                         value=(0.3, 1, 1),
                         constraint_axis=(True, False, False))
```